# Безопасность использования JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth, token, jwt

Подскажите пожалуйста почему все используют JWT при том, что он не безопасен.

Что я имею в виду, в блоке payload любого JWT есть поле **exp** (до какого момента живёт токен) и на него мы ориентируемся при проверке актуальный этот токен или нет, но подвох в том, что если кто-то когда-то получит ваш JWT (например даже просто зайдёт и скопирует его с localstorage), то можно изменить время жизни этого токена хоть на 10 или 20 лет и всё (я лично проверил это на одном из сайтов, редактировал токен через сайт https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/ продлил примерно на 6 или 7 лет).

Так вот вопрос, почему JWT так много используют, если у него есть такой огромный недостаток. Во всех видеороликах слышу такое "... генерируем токен и всё классно, по истечению его действия выдаём пользователю новый" но никто не говорит о что его можно редактировать. Да есть там такое понятие как refresh token но он нужен только тогда когда заканчивается время жизни access token и проверить, что это наш пользователь и ему нужно выдать новый.

Помогите пожалуйста понять зачем его использовать, если есть такие "косяки", возможно я ошибаюсь и чего-то не знаю, я не гуру.

Буду благодарен за любые ответы или ссылки на ресурсы где могу найти ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: токен так же состоит из signature, где тоже зашифровано exp поле. Проверять надо по нему ( так как оно зашифровано с секретным ключом ) https://habr.com/ru/post/340146/ Подделать signature уже не такая простая задача, поэтому можно доверять данным от туда ( конкретно полю exp )

Comment: @ThisMan то есть в signature не только зашит код для верификации, но и дополнительно добавлено время жизни токен, правильно я понимаю?
Я так-то понимаю что третья часть это по факту зашифрованный на Секретный ключ, но если же говорить о том, что мы получили уже какой-то активный токен, мы можем им манипулировать так как захотим

Comment: кодируется еще и payload, я скинул статью, там такая схема
`const SECRET_KEY = 'cAtwa1kkEy'
const unsignedToken = base64urlEncode(header) + '.' + base64urlEncode(payload)
const signature = HMAC-SHA256(unsignedToken, SECRET_KEY)`

Comment: @ThisMan Ага, я понял, спасибо большое за ответ